# Javascript clock, minutes behind

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, clock

Thought I'd do a little test, to test my skill set after being away from javascript for too long. Tried to be really cwleaver and create an object of a clock, sounds simple enough. I managed to create the clock etc with no trouble but after running the script after roughly 20 minutes, I noticed my clock was serval minutes behind! No idea what I've done.

This is only a little hobby project, I'm not gaining from this at all. Any criticisms accepted :)

```
function clock24(element){
            this.date=new Date;
            this.seconds=this.date.getSeconds();
            this.minutes=this.date.getMinutes();
            this.hours=this.date.getHours();
            this.ele=element;
            this.output={seconds:"00",minutes:"00",hours:"00"};
            this.update();
            var self=this;
            this.ele.html(this.output['hours']+":"+this.output['minutes']+":"+this.output['seconds']);
            this.increment=setInterval(function(){
                self.seconds++;
                if(self.seconds==60){
                    self.seconds=0;
                    self.minutes++;
                }
                if(self.minutes==60){
                    self.minutes=0;
                    self.hours++;
                }
                if(self.hours==24){
                    self.hours=0;
                }
                self.update();
                self.ele.html(self.output['hours']+":"+self.output['minutes']+":"+self.output['seconds']);
            },1000);
        }
        clock24.prototype={
            constructor:clock24,
            update:function(){
                this.output['seconds']=(this.seconds<10)?"0"+this.seconds.toString():this.seconds.toString();
                this.output['minutes']=(this.minutes<10)?"0"+this.minutes.toString():this.minutes.toString();
                this.output['hours']=(self.hours<10)?"0"+this.hours.toString():this.hours.toString();
            }
        }
```

My guesses are, something in the script takes too long to compute but is minimally noticeable? Or the way I've structured my script?

Can't put my finger on it, but! I bet it's something really stupid and I apologise for my stupid question in advance XD

Comment: `setInterval` is only guaranteed to have at *least* the specified interval pass before running the next iteration. This means that sometimes, it may run after 1020ms, or 1100 ms. It's simply not accurate enough to create a clock in this way. My suggestion is to use `new Date().getTime()` inside the interval to compute the exact amount of time that has *actually* elapsed between runs.

Comment: @Brennan ahh! ok, Thought it might be something like that, is there an alternative? Or should I use the `setInterval` and get the result from `Date.getSeconds()`?

Comment: [Here's an article about the `setInterval` issue.](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Comment: @sourRaspberri, I updated my comment to include a suggestion

Comment: Consumer-level operating systems aren't real-time, not to mention software running on them.

Comment: Cool thanks guys :) I shall use `Date.getTime()` as @Brennan suggested :d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it a bit like this:

```js
function clock24(el){

    var started, interval, seconds, minutes, hours;

    this.update = function(){

        var time = new Date(new Date().getTime() - started);
        
        seconds = time.getSeconds();
        minutes = time.getMinutes();
        hours = time.getHours();

        var pretty = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

        if(typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' && el instanceof jQuery)
            el.html( pretty );
        else
            el.innerHTML = pretty;
      
        return this;
      
    }
    
    this.start = function(){

        started = new Date().getTime();
        
        this.update();
        
        interval = setInterval(this.update, 1000);
        
        return this;
    
    }
    
    this.stop = function(){
      
        clearInterval(interval);
      
        return this;
      
    }

    return this;

}

var clock = clock24(document.body).start();
```

```css
body {
  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;

}
```

Each to their own though!

Comment: I like it, much neater and simpler way :) Thanks! :)

Comment: Additional thought, if I was to `delete` the object, would the interval clear automatically?

Comment: @sourRaspberri The [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator is a bit of a misnomer in JS as it only deletes a reference to an object, not the object itself. In order to truly remove an object you need to make sure there are no references to it whatsoever so that it can be garbage collected. In this case, the continued use of the [WindowsTimer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers) will stop your object from being garbage collected. See my addition of a `stop` method, which should be called before deleting.

Comment: @sourRaspberri in short; no. The interval needs to be cleared with the `clearInterval` method.

Comment: Cool :) thanks that's interesting to know. Thanks for getting back :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem as @Brennan suggested above in the comments. Here's my script incase anyone is interested in the future.

```
function clock24(element){
            this.ele=element;
            this.output={};
            this.update();
            var self=this;
            this.ele.html(this.output['hours']+":"+this.output['minutes']+":"+this.output['seconds']);
            this.increment=setInterval(function(){
                self.update();
                self.ele.html(self.output['hours']+":"+self.output['minutes']+":"+self.output['seconds']);
            },1000);
        }
        clock24.prototype={
            constructor:clock24,
            update:function(){
                //probably best not to use 'this'
                this.date=new Date();
                this.seconds=this.date.getSeconds();
                this.minutes=this.date.getMinutes();
                this.hours=this.date.getHours();
                this.output['seconds']=(this.seconds<10)?"0"+this.seconds.toString():this.seconds.toString();
                this.output['minutes']=(this.minutes<10)?"0"+this.minutes.toString():this.minutes.toString();
                this.output['hours']=(self.hours<10)?"0"+this.hours.toString():this.hours.toString();
            }
        }
```

I also quickly put together a 12 hour clock just incase n_n

```
function clock12(element){
            this.ele=element;
            this.output={};
            this.update();
            var self=this;
            this.ele.html(this.output['hours']+":"+this.output['minutes']+":"+this.output['seconds']+this.output['ampm']);
            this.increment=setInterval(function(){
                self.update();
                self.ele.html(self.output['hours']+":"+self.output['minutes']+":"+self.output['seconds']+self.output['ampm']);
            },1000);
        }
        clock12.prototype={
            constructor:clock12,
            update:function(){
                this.date=new Date();
                this.seconds=this.date.getSeconds();
                this.minutes=this.date.getMinutes();
                this.hours=this.date.getHours();
                this.output['ampm']=this.hours>='12'?'pm':'am';
                this.hours=this.hours%12;
                this.output['seconds']=(this.seconds<10)?"0"+this.seconds.toString():this.seconds.toString();
                this.output['minutes']=(this.minutes<10)?"0"+this.minutes.toString():this.minutes.toString();
                this.output['hours']=this.hours.toString() ? this.hours.toString():'12';

            }
        }
```

Still freezes (can tell when applied to the title of the document, checking whilst on other pages) but the time is always correct.